# crunch password generation with multiple character sets

Tags: passwords, password-cracking, kali-linux, crunch

I'm trying to use crunch to generate a password list. However, if I add all necessary characters into one character set, as in:

### file: charset_huge.lst

complex = [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890!@#$%^&*()]

... then I cannot create multiple repetition rules, such as:

- no more than 2 repeating UPPERCASE characters in a row
- no more than 2 repeating special characters in a row
- no more than 2 repeating numeric characters in a row

My (current) character set file looks like this:

### file: charset.lst

lower = [abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz]

upper = [ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]

numeric = [1234567890]

special = [!@#$%^&*()]

In doing some research it looked to me that you could specify multiple sets within the same character set file by using the + sign, ie:

crunch 5 5 -f charset.lst lower + upper -o passwordlist.lst

The above command does in fact work but it doesn't register the second set (upper). It only produces a list based on the first set (lower).

My hope is that I'm doing something wrong and that multiple character sets (from the same character set file) IS possible and that I can use -t to specify multiple patterns.

Does any one know if this is possible? Thanks very much for guidance / examples!

Edit 1: to answer Conner's question, my intentions are to generate a very large listing of password combinations with which to feed to hashcat to perform a brute-force attack on an md5 hash. This is an ethical attack. Thanks for pointing that out Conner!

Comment: I'm not 100% on what you're trying to do here (generate a password list to use to make passwords, or a password list to use to crack passwords).  But assuming the former it is worth mentioning that your proposed password repetition rules actually make your passwords *less* secure.  Let the thing repeat characters if that's what the dice happen to roll.

Comment: Wow, I did not catch the fact that I didn't state my intentions. I am generating a (likely) massive list of passwords with which to feed into hashcat in order to bruteforce an md5 hash. For what it's worth, this is an ethical attack however I have no means to back that statement up. If I put all my characters into a single character set (lower, upper, #'s, and 6 special chars) my password list would be on the order of 1PT... which is far too large. I'm hoping that, if the above is possible, I can whittle that size down considerably.

Comment: AFAIK you can't give rules to crunch (like the repetition rules) nor select more than 1 charset (from all the examples I've read), but I may be wrong. You may want to check -p or -q.